# Hosmer-Lemeshow goodness of Fit test in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, glm

I have estimated a glm in python. How can I perform Hosmer-Lemeshow goodness

of fit test for this model in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way, the code is not of the best quality however it works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2
pihat=model.predict()
pihatcat=pd.cut(pihat, np.percentile(pihat,[0,25,50,75,100]),labels=False,include_lowest=True) #here I've chosen only 4 groups


meanprobs =[0]*4 
expevents =[0]*4
obsevents =[0]*4 
meanprobs2=[0]*4 
expevents2=[0]*4
obsevents2=[0]*4 

for i in range(4):
   meanprobs[i]=np.mean(pihat[pihatcat==i])
   expevents[i]=np.sum(pihatcat==i)*np.array(meanprobs[i])
   obsevents[i]=np.sum(data.r[pihatcat==i])
   meanprobs2[i]=np.mean(1-pihat[pihatcat==i])
   expevents2[i]=np.sum(pihatcat==i)*np.array(meanprobs2[i])
   obsevents2[i]=np.sum(1-data.r[pihatcat==i]) 


data1={'meanprobs':meanprobs,'meanprobs2':meanprobs2}
data2={'expevents':expevents,'expevents2':expevents2}
data3={'obsevents':obsevents,'obsevents2':obsevents2}
m=pd.DataFrame(data1)
e=pd.DataFrame(data2)
o=pd.DataFrame(data3)

tt=sum(sum((np.array(o)-np.array(e))**2/np.array(e))) #the statistic for the test, which follows,under the null hypothesis, the chi-squared distribution with degrees of freedom equal to amount of groups - 2 
pvalue=1-chi2.cdf(tt,2)
pvalue
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2

# This could be made into a neat function of Hosmer-Lemeshow. 
def HosmerLemeshow (model,Y):
    pihat=model.predict()
    pihatcat=pd.cut(pihat, np.percentile(pihat,[0,25,50,75,100]),labels=False,include_lowest=True) #here we've chosen only 4 groups


    meanprobs =[0]*4 
    expevents =[0]*4
    obsevents =[0]*4 
    meanprobs2=[0]*4 
    expevents2=[0]*4
    obsevents2=[0]*4 

    for i in range(4):
       meanprobs[i]=np.mean(pihat[pihatcat==i])
       expevents[i]=np.sum(pihatcat==i)*np.array(meanprobs[i])
       obsevents[i]=np.sum(Y[pihatcat==i])
       meanprobs2[i]=np.mean(1-pihat[pihatcat==i])
       expevents2[i]=np.sum(pihatcat==i)*np.array(meanprobs2[i])
       obsevents2[i]=np.sum(1-Y[pihatcat==i]) 


    data1={'meanprobs':meanprobs,'meanprobs2':meanprobs2}
    data2={'expevents':expevents,'expevents2':expevents2}
    data3={'obsevents':obsevents,'obsevents2':obsevents2}
    m=pd.DataFrame(data1)
    e=pd.DataFrame(data2)
    o=pd.DataFrame(data3)
    
    # The statistic for the test, which follows, under the null hypothesis,
    # The chi-squared distribution with degrees of freedom equal to amount of groups - 2. Thus 4 - 2 = 2
    tt=sum(sum((np.array(o)-np.array(e))**2/np.array(e))) 
    pvalue=1-chi2.cdf(tt,2)

    return pd.DataFrame([[chi2.cdf(tt,2).round(2), pvalue.round(2)]],columns = ["Chi2", "p - value"])
    
HosmerLemeshow(glm_full,Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hosmer-Lemeshow is a test which is applied only when your response variable is binary. I said this because Simple Linear Regression and Poisson Regression belong to Generalized Linear Models but the response variable in them is not binary.

I haven't found any function in Python in order to apply Hosmer-Lemeshow test so I will do this test with the traditional way (calculate the value of test statistic and then calculate the pvalue).

As test statistic we will use this function

[image]

where:

O_{1g} is the observed Y = 1 events in the g-th decile group

O_{0g} is the observed Y = 0 events in the g-th decile group

E_{1g} is the expected Y = 1 events in the g-th decile group

E_{0g} is the expected Y = 0 events in the g-th decile group

Also, we should keep in our mind that this test statistic asymptotically follows X^2_{(G - 2)}

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosmer%E2%80%93Lemeshow_test#Calculation_of_the_statistic)

In order to do this test I need these imports

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from scipy.stats import chi2 #In order to be able to calculate the pvalue
```

Let's suppose that there is a dependent variable Y in your code which is a Series object and this holds the binary values we observed (0 or 1). Also, let's assume that there is a variable X in your code which is a dataframe and holds all the independent variables of your model.

```
#We will calculate the the predicted probabilities of success (Y = 1) for every data via
#the model we have created

#Let's suppose that you have named your model log_reg

predictions = log_reg(X)

#Now we will create a dataframe with two columns. The first column will represent the
#predicted probabilies and the second column will represent the binary data we observed

hl_df = pd.DataFrame({

"P_i": predictions,

"Outcome": Y

})
```

In order to do the Hosmer-Lemeshow test we have to discretize the variable which holds the predicted probabilities (in our case P_i) into equal-sized buckets based on sample quantiles. In the Hosmer-Lemeshow test we usually create 10 deciles but you can use for example 4 quantiles. It's up to you.

In order to do this we will use the [pd.qcut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) function.

```
hl_df["decile"] = pd.qcut(hl_df["P_i"],10)
```

Now, we will calculate the $O_{0g}$ and $O_{1g}$

```
#We will calculate all the observed ones in every decile

obsevents_1 = hl_df["Outcome"].groupby(hl_df.decile).sum()

#We will find all the observed zeroes of every decile if we substract the obsevents_1 from the
#number of elements in every decile

obsevents_0 = hl_df["Outcome"].groupby(hl_df.decile).count() - obsevents_1
```

Now we will calculate the E_{0g} E_{1g}

As we know the variable Y is a binary variable which means that it follows Bernoulli(p_i). So, the expected value of the variable Y is p_i. Also, we should keep in our minds that every value of Y is independent from the other. So, the expected number of outcomes of Y = 1 in the g-th decile is p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + ... + p_n where n is the number of p_i which belong in the g-th decile.

```
expevents_1 = hl_df["P_i"].groupby(hl_df.decile).sum()

#We will find the expected number of events Y = 0 for every decile by substracting the
#expevents_1 from the number of elements in every decile

expevents_0 = hl_df["P_i"].groupby(hl_df.decile).count() - expevents_1
```

Now, we are ready to calculate the value of test statistic

```
hl = (((obsevents_0 - expevents_0)**2)/(expevents_0)).sum() + (((obsevents_1 - expevents_1)**2)/(expevents_1)).sum()
```

Now, we will calculate the pvalue

```
pvalue = 1 - chi2.cdf(hl , 10 - 2)

#if you choose 4 quartiles instead of 10 deciles you should write pvalue = 1 - chi2.cdf(hl,4 - 2)
```

Now, based on the pvalue and the level of significance you want to apply you can decide if you will reject or not the null hypothesis.

I would like to mention that for the above code I used [this](https://jbhender.github.io/Stats506/F18/GP/Group5.html) source.